# AngularJS Routing is not routing

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use the routing feature of angularJS, but so far it will not include my html templates (`user.html` and `overview.html`, which are in the same folder as `index.html`).
For information only: the expression `{{test}}` is working.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PARA Liste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="angularJsApplication" ng-controller="angularJsController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Para Liste</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#overview">overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#user1">user1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#user2">user2 - {{test}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="ng-view"></div>
</div>
<script src="js/angularJsApplication.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularJsApplicationController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

angularJsApplication.js:

```
var app = angular.module("angularJsApplication", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when("/#", {
           templateURL : "overview.html"
       })
       .when("/overview", {
           templateURL : "overview.html"
       })
       .when("/user1", {
           templateURL : "user.html"
       })
       .when("/user2", {
           templateURL : "user.html"
       })
});
```

angularJsApplicationController.js:

```
app.controller("angularJsController", function($scope){
    $scope.test = "testTestTEST";
});
```

user.html:
`<h1>user</h1>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its typo mistake :

not `templateURL` It''s `templateUrl`

So,it should be.

```
templateUrl: "overview.html"
```

Comment: You can close the question if it working for you by accepting it.Dont forget to upvote